# Resizing adds on the stroke width

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, stroke

I have a graphic in illustrator CC that I need to resize. The original size is about 3.5, when I go to resize it to 10.5 it bumps itself up to 10.6 adding the dimensions of the outer most stroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *Preferences → General* check *"Use Preview Bounds"*:

[image]

This will use the visual appearance of objects to create their bounding box, rather than the paths themselves so resizing will take in to account the width of strokes or any effects etc.

*Mostly copied from [my answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/83641/52050).*